# python subprocess shouldn't run from within the folder

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use the **C&C NLP library** in my mac and it uses terminal as its interface. so naturally I'm trying to run the command from my python, but here's what happens:

```
candc:could not open model configuration file for reading:models/config
```

turns out candc should not be called from the same directory, and should be called from outside of the binary folder, something like "bin/candc".
how can I make this work?

this is my code:

```
cmd="candc/bin/candc --models models"  
subprocess.check_output('{} | tee /dev/stderr'.format( cmd ), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `cwd` argument with your desired working directory.

For example, if you want to run it as `bin/candc` from the `candc` directory:

```
import os
cmd="bin/candc --models models"  
subprocess.check_output('{} | tee /dev/stderr'.format( cmd ), shell=True, cwd=os.path.abspath('candc'))
```

(I'm not sure whether you actually need os.path.abspath. Do test both with and without it.)

Comment: thank you I didn't know about the cwd argument. now it works just fine.

Comment: there is a new problem I am facing now... I will have to be able to add other commands on the same terminal process; as when it is running the candc parser, I give it a sentence and it parses the sentence. how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: @mid Ask another question explaining it better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path in `cmd`:

```
cmd = "/home/your-username/python-programs/cnc/candc/bin/canc --models models
```

Whatever that full path might be. You can use (if you're on linux) `pwd` inside the `candc` directory to find out what it is.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but the problem persists.